# mysql error 'TYPE=MyISAM'

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error, myisam

Below query I'm executing in Ubuntu 12, MySQL 5.1 version and receiving error as mentioned:

```
CREATE TABLE mantis_config_table (
    config_id VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    project_id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    access_reqd INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    type INTEGER DEFAULT 90,
    value LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (config_id, project_id, user_id)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 9

Can anyone suggest what's wrong?

Comment: yes replacing `TYPE=MyISAM` with `ENGINE=MyISAM` works ! thanks guys

Comment: So you won't be correcting anyone's answer? :P

Comment: i will for sure in a day or two

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Replace

`TYPE=MyISAM`

with

`ENGINE=MyISAM`

The problem was "TYPE=MyISAM" which should be "ENGINE=MyISAM" as per MySQL version updates - a simple search / replace has fix it.

Answer (score 29):

Do not use the keyword `TYPE` anymore. Use `ENGINE` instead.

> TYPE keyword is depreciated (since 5.0) and not supported in MySQL5.5

```
CREATE TABLE mantis_config_table 
( 
   ...   
) 
ENGINE = MyISAM;
^^^^^^--------------------- HERE
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. With version info.

Answer (score 15):

In newer MySQL Versions its:

```
ENGINE=MyISAM
```

here the tutorial [(MySQL)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html)

Comment: Thank you for the URI to the corresponding documentation.

Answer (score 7):

Use ENGINE instead of TYPE

```
ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case, fixed the issue by replacing the older dialect with newer one (compatible with the database):

old:
`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`
new:`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect`

Comment: I had this issue with H2 running in MySql mode + spring generate DDL. This fixed it