# Some help to find the error in this SQL statement

Tags: mysql, database

Can anyone help me check this sql statement am getting this error:

```
Error

>     SQL query:
>     
>     CREATE TABLE `dp_banks` (
>     `id` int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
>     `owner` int( 11 ) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `bname` varchar( 128 ) NOT NULL default '',
>     `baddress` varchar( 128 ) NOT NULL default '',
>     `bcity` varchar( 64 ) NOT NULL default '',
>     `bzip` varchar( 16 ) NOT NULL default '',
>     `bcountry` char( 2 ) NOT NULL default '',
>     `bstate` varchar( 32 ) NOT NULL default '',
>     `bphone` varchar( 32 ) NOT NULL default '',
>     `bnameacc` varchar( 128 ) NOT NULL default '',
>     `baccount` varchar( 32 ) NOT NULL default '',
>     `btype` char( 2 ) NOT NULL default '',
>     `brtgnum` varchar( 9 ) NOT NULL default '',
>     `bswift` varchar( 32 ) NOT NULL default '',
>     `status` tinyint( 1 ) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `default` tinyint( 1 ) NOT NULL default '0',
>     PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
>     ) TYPE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
>     
>     MySQL said: Documentation
>     #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
> use near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 19
```

Here is the main code:

```
-- 
-- Table structure for table `dp_banks`
-- 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dp_banks`;
CREATE TABLE `dp_banks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `owner` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `bname` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `baddress` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `bcity` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `bzip` varchar(16) NOT NULL default '',
  `bcountry` char(2) NOT NULL default '',
  `bstate` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `bphone` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `bnameacc` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `baccount` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `btype` char(2) NOT NULL default '',
  `brtgnum` varchar(9) NOT NULL default '',
  `bswift` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `default` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

I would appreciate any quick help. I have tried all possible best to get this debugged but all to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql error 'TYPE=MyISAM'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471075/mysql-error-type-myisam)

Comment: possible duplicate of [1064 error in CREATE TABLE ... TYPE=MYISAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428755/1064-error-in-create-table-type-myisam)

Answer (score 2):

The `TYPE` table option was deprecated in MySQL 4.0. You should use the `ENGINE` option instead:

```
ENGINE = MyISAM
```

From the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

> The older TYPE option was synonymous with ENGINE. TYPE has been deprecated since MySQL 4.0 but is still supported for backward compatibility in MySQL 5.1 (excepting MySQL 5.1.7). **Since MySQL 5.1.8, it produces a warning. It is removed in MySQL 5.5.** You should not use TYPE in any new applications, and you should immediately begin conversion of existing applications to use ENGINE instead.

<sup>*Source:* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html</sup>

I'm guessing one of the two highlighted sentences explains the reasoning for the error you are seeing.

Comment: @CitsSolutions: I see you're new at [so]. If an answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. This helps keep your acceptance level up in addition to recognizing a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is:

```
ENGINE = MYISAM
```