# Error while creating a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a table in mysql database with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE `abcd` (
`A` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' primary key,
`B` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`C` datetime,
`D` datetime,
`E` varchar(16),
`F` varchar(16),
`G` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`H` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`I` int(20),
`J` int(20),
`K` datetime,
) TYPE=MyISAM ;
```

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ') TYPE=MyISAM' at line 13.

I have also used ENGINE=MyISAM but getting the same error.
Can anyone explain where there is syntax error in the code?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: this is quite hard to read, but there is a comma before the closing brackets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1064 error in CREATE TABLE ... TYPE=MYISAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428755/1064-error-in-create-table-type-myisam)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql error 'TYPE=MyISAM'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471075/mysql-error-type-myisam)

Comment: @KevinEsche ..... Thanks for your answer....it worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the comma before the parenthesis, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `abcd` (
`A` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' primary key,
`B` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`C` datetime,
`D` datetime,
`E` varchar(16),
`F` varchar(16),
`G` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`H` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`I` int(20),
`J` int(20),
`K` datetime
) TYPE=MyISAM ;
```

Comment: This worked......Was a silly mistake that i didnt notice ;) .....Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

working off what @Thanos said, it is engine, not type

```
CREATE TABLE `abcd` (
`A` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' primary key,
`B` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`C` datetime,
`D` datetime,
`E` varchar(16),
`F` varchar(16),
`G` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`H` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`I` int(20),
`J` int(20),
`K` datetime
) engine=MyISAM ;
```

**tested**

Answer (score 1):

You have an unnecessary comma after `K datetime`. This is throwing the error mentioned.

Also, use `ENGINE=MYISAM` instead of `TYPE=MYISAM`.
Here's the query.

```
CREATE TABLE `abcd` (
`A` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' primary key,
`B` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`C` datetime,
`D` datetime,
`E` varchar(16),
`F` varchar(16),
`G` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`H` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`I` int(20),
`J` int(20),
`K` datetime
) ENGINE=MyISAM ;
```