# GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, spring-data

I am a novice in hibernate world and facing,

```
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
```

exception while I run my stand-alone programe in hibernate 5.2.9 version. But in hibernate 4 version all my code runs well. I looked for many questions and solve but not working answer i got.

> Configuration file

```
hibernate.cfg.xml

    <hibernate-configuration>
      <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="com.test.hibernate14417.MyTable"></mapping>
      </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

> Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Hibernate14417</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <repositories>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

> Utility file

```
package com.test.hibernate14417;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;


public class ExecuteUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory SESSION_FACTORY=buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();

            Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry).buildMetadata();

            return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }

    }

    public static SessionFactory getSESSION_FACTORY() {
        return SESSION_FACTORY;
    }

    public static void shutdown(){
        getSESSION_FACTORY().close();
    }

}
```

> Entity file

```
package com.test.hibernate14417;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;




@Entity
public class MyTable implements Serializable {

    @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



}
```

> Main method

```
package com.test.hibernate14417;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyTable mt=new MyTable();
        mt.setName("Man");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory=ExecuteUtil.getSESSION_FACTORY();

        Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();


        try {
          session.getTransaction().begin();

          session.save(mt);

          session.getTransaction().commit();

           session.close();
           sessionFactory.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }


    }
```

> Console

```
cd D:\Netbeans\Hibernate14417; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_121" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath com.test.hibernate14417.Main\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_121\\bin\\java.exe\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\""
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Hibernate14417 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ Hibernate14417 ---
Apr 14, 2017 10:41:51 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final}
Apr 14, 2017 10:41:51 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Apr 14, 2017 10:41:53 AM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Apr 14, 2017 10:41:54 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Apr 14, 2017 10:41:54 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Apr 14, 2017 10:41:54 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test]
Apr 14, 2017 10:41:54 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Apr 14, 2017 10:41:54 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Apr 14, 2017 10:41:54 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Apr 14, 2017 10:41:55 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Apr 14, 2017 10:41:55 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
Hibernate: drop table if exists hibernate_sequence
Apr 14, 2017 10:41:58 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@24111ef1] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: drop table if exists MyTable
Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint) type=MyISAM
Apr 14, 2017 10:41:58 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@531f4093] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Apr 14, 2017 10:41:58 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at com.test.hibernate14417.ExecuteUtil.buildSessionFactory(ExecuteUtil.java:29)
    at com.test.hibernate14417.ExecuteUtil.<clinit>(ExecuteUtil.java:20)
    at com.test.hibernate14417.Main.main(Main.java:21)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1571)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1666)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2972)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2902)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.execute(Statement.java:529)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 13 more

Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Apr 14, 2017 10:41:58 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at com.test.hibernate14417.ExecuteUtil.buildSessionFactory(ExecuteUtil.java:29)
    at com.test.hibernate14417.ExecuteUtil.<clinit>(ExecuteUtil.java:20)
    at com.test.hibernate14417.Main.main(Main.java:21)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table 'test.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1571)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1666)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2972)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2902)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.execute(Statement.java:529)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 13 more

Hibernate: create table MyTable (id integer not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id)) type=MyISAM
Apr 14, 2017 10:41:58 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at com.test.hibernate14417.ExecuteUtil.buildSessionFactory(ExecuteUtil.java:29)
    at com.test.hibernate14417.ExecuteUtil.<clinit>(ExecuteUtil.java:20)
    at com.test.hibernate14417.Main.main(Main.java:21)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1571)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1666)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2972)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2902)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.execute(Statement.java:529)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 13 more

Apr 14, 2017 10:41:58 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@7776ab'
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:454)
    at com.test.hibernate14417.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You should try a different dialects like`org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` OR  `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect` OR `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect` to see which one works for you.

All in all , your current dialect is generating , `type=MyISAM` while it should be , `ENGINE=MyISAM` in create table query.

[mysql error 'TYPE=MyISAM'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471075/mysql-error-type-myisam)

You should read this too , [Why do I need to configure the SQL dialect of a data source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012799/why-do-i-need-to-configure-the-sql-dialect-of-a-data-source)

Your logs say that this query was tried to be executed , `create table MyTable (id integer not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id)) type=MyISAM`  so you should try to execute that query directly on mysql command prompt to see if that works for your MySQL version.

Also, in question do specify your MySQL version too.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: It'worked! I tried first dialect - `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: I am using mysql 8.0.21 . None of the dialect is working for me

Comment: I'm using Mysql 5.7 None of them worked for me

Comment: I am using mysql 8.0.27 for macos 10.15 catalina and anyway not dialect work for me ='(

Comment: You can use another dialect like `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect`

Answer (score 14):

You are using an updated version of `MySQL` but using and **old** `dialect`

Use either,

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
```

OR

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
```

in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.

This prevents you from getting `dialect` issues.

Comment: life saver answer

Answer (score 6):

The reason you are facing this error might be any of the reasons below:-

- The column name in the DB Script and the model/entity class are different.
- There is a spelling mistake in your configuration file while mentioning property value.
- The MySQL version is not getting matched with the dialect that you are mentioning.

I was facing this error because I change the column names in my DATABASE SCRIPT but forgot to change it in the Model/Entity class. So, after 4 hours of pulling my hairs I simply did this and my application started running.

Answer (score 3):

Change in hibernate configuration XML file.

```
  <!-- SQL dialect -->      
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not particularly related to the cause of the author's problem. But I had a similar error because I used one of the DB keywords as a variable name.

I had `String group` as a column in my table, and the query was throwing an error because the system thought that `group` was not a that it must create column, but a command word.

Comment: As this is not actusally an answer to the question, consider adding it as a comment instead.

Comment: Thanks! A good suggestion :) 
unfortunately, for now,  i have not enough reputation points to do this :(

Comment: Aah.. apologies, I overlooked this doing my "review" duties.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, I was using dialect as **MySqlDialect**.

I resolved it by changing the dialect to **org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect** and tables got created.

Answer (score 1):

If it is in a **spring boot application** insert the following property.

*spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect*

Or else if you used a **separate configuration file** then include the following code

*properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect");*

Answer (score 0):

Check your property value mistakes.

It happens sometime, when you just simply forget the **'t'** in **Dialec**, which has to be **Dialect**, simply spelling mistake or value kind of mistake there is inside your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. And indeed, it is the dialect issue, although none of the options provided by Sabir helped me out (with due respect) but changing it from MySQL5Dialect to MySQL8Dialect helped me resolve the issue.

So if none of the above 3 options provided above works, go for **MySQL8Dialect**.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more variation of a dialect that worked for me when I tried to connect my Spring Boot application to Google Cloud MySQL DB: `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the entity/model field names that are not conflicting with DB reserved keywords.

I had the same error in my Model entity, I had a variable named `Order` which somehow conflicts with the Database reserved keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue, changed a column name from "end" to "endTime" and it fixed.